# Grab a text between value and a symbol .NET

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have a column in database (Sql Server) wich contains values like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\f0\fs22 Negative}
```

where `\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\f0\fs22` is the text formatting (size, font...).
I'm not interested in this.

I only want to extract the text / string `Negative`, but the same column may contain also:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\f0\fs22 Slightly Cloudy}
```

In other words, I want to grab only the text between `fs22` and `}`

Expected results: `Slightly Cloudy` or `Negative`

How to do it in C# or VB.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
(?<=fs22\s*)[^}]+(?=}$)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
(?<=\\fs22 )[^}]+(?=})
```

This will match anything between `\fs22` and `}` while not containing said delimiters in the match (this is achieved using lookaround assertions). In C# this would look like

```
var value = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=\\fs22 )[^}]+(?=})").Value;
```

or in VB:

```
Dim value = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=\\fs22 )[^}]+(?=})").Value
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> '{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\f0\fs22 Negative}',
>> '{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\f0\fs22 Slightly Cloudy}' |
>> %{ [Regex]::Match($_, '(?<=\\fs22 )[^}]+(?=})') }
>>


Groups   : {Negative}
Success  : True
Captures : {Negative}
Index    : 69
Length   : 8
Value    : Negative

Groups   : {Slightly Cloudy}
Success  : True
Captures : {Slightly Cloudy}
Index    : 69
Length   : 15
Value    : Slightly Cloudy
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using SubString?

```
string s = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\f0\fs22 Negative}";
int i = s.LastIndexOf(@"\fs22 ");
string x = s.Substring(i + 6, s.Length - i - 6 - 1);
// 6 = length of string "\fs22 "
// 1 = minus the } at the end
```

I think SubString might also be better performance wise. I think regex is not the most effecient way to approach a simple string manipulation.

Comment: It's also a lot more code, harder to read and understand (ok, this comes from someone who can usually read regexes easily) and less resistant to change, e.g. if the start marker changes to `\fs122` you need to remember to change all instances of `6` to `7`.

Comment: still i will try both solutions with more data, and decide which is much faster, but either one solved my question, tanks to all

Comment: @Flavius69 it's easy to define the delimiters in two seperate strings and test the length of those strings instead of the magic numbers 6 and 7, but the example above is easier to understand and I merely gave it as an alternative to resolving the OP's problem not using regex.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION SOLVED]

 'With Regular Expression

```
Private Function _CompareTextWithString(ByVal regexp As String, ByVal _theTextWhereToSearch As String) As String

    Dim EXPreg As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

    '1º - The Regular Expression
    Dim expresaoREGULAR As String = regexp
    ' EX: "(?<=fs22\s*)[^}]+(?=}$)"

    '2º - Associate the expression to a Variavel Regex
    EXPreg = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(expresaoREGULAR, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    '3º
    ' Check if matches with
    Dim check As Match = EXPreg.Match(_theTextWhereToSearch)

    If (check.Success) Then

        Return check.Value ' Matches
    Else
        Return False ' No Matches
    End If

End Function
'Usage
Private Sub _btExecRegex_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _btExecRegex.Click
    _txtResult.Text = _CompareTextWithString("(?<=fs22\s*)[^}]+(?=}$)", _
                                                "{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\f0\fs22 Negative}")
End Sub

'With Substring
Private Function _returnValueFromStr(ByVal _str As String, ByVal _strFilterLastIndexOf As String, ByVal _lastCharOrChars As Integer) As String
    'Last ocourence of the filter
    Dim i As Integer = _str.LastIndexOf(_strFilterLastIndexOf)
    'size of Filter
    Dim f As Integer = _strFilterLastIndexOf.Length

    'Return the value from _str wich is filtered 
    'with _strFilterLastIndexOf and at the end -1 (or -2 ...) the char i don't need

    Return _str.Substring(i + f, _str.Length - i - f - _lastCharOrChars)

End Function
'Usage
Private Sub _btExecutar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _btExecutarSubStr.Click
    _txtResult.Text = _returnValueFromStr("{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\f0\fs22 Negative}", _
                                             "\fs22 ", 1)
End Sub
```